# What does the environmental variable "term" mean in the mongo config?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to create a sharded mongo cluster and came across the env. variable "term", with value "xterm". Need help to understand the config field.

```
environment:
    TERM: xterm
```

Comment: What is the context for this setting (for example, the filename or path)?  This sounds like O/S configuration rather than something specific to MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TERM` is an env var that contains the terminal emulator used by your system. This var is not related to MongoDB.

In my Ubuntu 16.04, if I type `echo $TERM`, I'll get `xterm-256color`.

If you are using Docker, that `TERM: xterm` means that the terminal emulator used when you access your container will be `xterm`.

`TERM` affects MongoDB in the following way: Different terminal emulators generate different [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) when you press keys like **Arrows, Home, End, Delete, etc;** Mongo Shell, that runs on top of the emulator, will translate those sequences into its own 'language' to guarantee that each keystroke will present the same result in different terminals. Mongo uses [Linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) to do this job.

The value of `TERM` is not that important for 'keystroke processing'. Mongo Shell will try to translate the escape sequence from each terminal 'language' it supports. On the other hand, `TERM` is used to decide if the shell can show colors or not.

Comment: The  `mongo` shell doesn't require any specific `TERM` settings that I'm aware of. If your terminal supports ANSI colour codes or other extended  sequences you could perhaps use these in scripts, but colour isn't used by default (as at MongoDB 4.2). [`Keyboard Shortcuts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#keyboard-shortcuts) for the `mongo` shell  are documented, but if  you have any other suggestions you could let the team know via a [DOCS issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS/) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.

Comment: You are right. I kind of mixed different things in my original answer. I edited it to separate what `TERM` is and how Mongo Shell uses it. Please, correct me if I'm writing crap about the Mongo Shell part. Would be great to learn from a Mongo team member

Comment: Nice improvement including mention of  the `Linenoise` library. I believe many of the Emacs-style keyboard shortcuts are implemented in the `mongo` shell rather than upstream (see [SERVER-4312](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4312) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker) so I expect the MongoDB documentation will still be the best reference. I'm not sure if there are any extra details left to discover in the source code, but the keyboard shortcuts haven't changed significantly since MongoDB 2.2.